# Determining the limit of this series

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

$$ \sum_{n=0}^\infty  \frac{(-2)^n + 2^{3n}}{3^n4^n} = $$

$$ \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n2^n}{3^n4^n} + \sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^n = $$

$$ \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n\frac{1}{6^n} + \sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^n = $$

The second sum is a geometric series, and its limit is

$$ \frac{1}{1 - 2/3} = 3 $$

However, I am having trouble finding the limit of the first Sum. How else can I approach this question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both are geometric series:
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-2)^n}{3^n \cdot 4^n} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty  \left(\frac{-2}{3\cdot 4}\right)^n = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(\frac{-1}{6}\right)^n
$$
and
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{2^{3n}}{3^n\cdot 4^n} = 
\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{8^n}{3^n\cdot 4^n} =
\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(\frac{8}{3\cdot 4}\right)^n =
\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^n
$$

Answer (score 4):

The first sum is also geometric. 
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\frac{-1}6\right)^n=\frac1{1+1/6}.$$

Answer (score 1):

first part is also a geometric sequence $$|q|<1 \rightarrow a+aq+aq^2+aq^3+\cdots=\frac{a}{1-q}\\1-\frac{1}{6}+\frac{1}{36}-\cdots=\frac{1}{1-\frac{-1}{6}}$$